# Do divergence and curl uniquely determine a 3D vector field?

Tags: vector-fields, mathematics

I feel this should be true, but I'm not sure how. If it's true, can someone tell me how? If it's false, just say so in a comment.

Why I feel it's feel true? I have a clumsy reason. Divergence is like a dot product and curl is like a cross product. Dot product and cross product are not individually invertible, but together, they are...right? If you're given the values of $\vec v_1$, $\,\vec v_2\cdot\vec v_1$, $\,\vec v_2\times\vec v_1$, you have enough information to recover $\vec v_2$. This is because you can recover both the components $v_2\cos\theta$ and $v_2\sin\theta$.

But then again, divergence and curl are only derivatives. So maybe they only determine a vector field upto the addition of a constant vector. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, if the divergence and curl goes to zero sufficiently rapidly as r tends to infinity, then they uniquely determine the vector field. Look for Helmholtz theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

Comment: Counter example without BC: constant functions. All have the same div and curl.

Comment: @KP99 Thanks. That's what I was looking for. Not sure why the r tends to infinity condition exists though.

Comment: @lalala I think I covered that in the last paragraph of the post

Comment: It is a consequence of boundary conditions, that the scalar and vector parts of the decomposition should approach zero as r tends to infinity. You can also see that the integrals for scalar and vector parts should yield a finite quantity, so the integrands must drop faster than $1/r^2$.

Comment: @KP99, or the volume could be kept finite, and boundary integrals appear in the decomposition, as in your wiki link :-)